# Null pointer exception for adding to a Jlist in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception

I am trying to add a set of data called `deliveryToAdd`, however when I click the add button it will give the following error (it give a lot of lines in the output but this is the first few lines):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fastcourierservice.gui.AddDelivery.saveItem(AddDelivery.java:360)
    at fastcourierservice.gui.AddDelivery.btnAddDeliveryActionPerformed(AddDelivery.java:265)
    at fastcourierservice.gui.AddDelivery.access$100(AddDelivery.java:17)
    at fastcourierservice.gui.AddDelivery$2.actionPerformed(AddDelivery.java:101)
```

When I click on the error it takes me to this line in the code:

```
deliveryRecord.addDeliveryWithCost(deliveryToAdd, Cost);
```

This is the full code for this method which is called in the add button:

```
private void saveItem() {
        if (this.isSaveable()) {
            int packageCount = Integer.parseInt(txtNoOfPackages.getText());
            double costPerKG = Double.parseDouble(txtCostPerKg.getText());
            double weight = Double.parseDouble(txtWeight.getText());
            double Cost = costPerKG * weight;
            String consignmentNumber = txtConsignmentNumber.getText();
            Address colAddress = new Address(txtColAddressLine1.getText(), txtColAddressLine2.getText(), txtColCity.getText(), txtColPostcode.getText());
            Address delAddress = new Address(txtDelAddressLine1.getText(), txtDelAddressLine2.getText(), txtDelCity.getText(), txtDelPostcode.getText());
            Delivery deliveryToAdd = new Delivery(consignmentNumber, packageCount, weight, colAddress, delAddress);

            //Test results
            System.out.println(deliveryToAdd);
            System.out.println(packageCount);
            System.out.println(weight);
            System.out.println(colAddress);
            System.out.println(delAddress);
            System.out.println(Cost);

            deliveryRecord.addDeliveryWithCost(deliveryToAdd, Cost);
            System.out.println(deliveryToAdd);
        }
    }
```

I used the System.out.println(); to test the results the deliveryToAdd shows the consignmentNumber and the rest show as expected.

This is the start of this class where the deliveryRecord was declared:

```
public class AddDelivery extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private DeliveryRecord deliveryRecord;

     public void setDeliveryRecord(DeliveryRecord objTarget)
    {

        deliveryRecord = objTarget;
    }
    /**
     * Creates new form AddDelivery
     */
    public AddDelivery() {
        initComponents();
    }
```

This is the DeliveryRecord class

```
public class DeliveryRecord implements IDeliveryRecord, Serializable {

    private ArrayList<Delivery> deliveries;
    private transient ArrayList<IObserver> observers = null;
    private Customer owner;

    private ISubjectImpl subjectDelegate;

    /**
     * Default Constructor creates an empty DeliveryRecord object that 
     * contains no deliveries. Required for serialisation
     */
    public DeliveryRecord()
    {
        this.deliveries = new ArrayList<>();
        this.subjectDelegate = new ISubjectImpl();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor that creates a DeliveryRecord that is "owned" by the provided customer
     * @param owner - A Customer object that "owns" the DeliveryRecord object 
     * that is being constructed
     */
    public DeliveryRecord(Customer owner)
    {
        this();
        this.owner = owner;
        this.registerObserver(this.owner);
    }

    public ArrayList<Delivery> getDeliveryList()
    {
        ArrayList<Delivery> listResult = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Delivery objCurrDelivery : this.deliveries)
        {
            listResult.add(objCurrDelivery);
        }
        return listResult;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addDelivery(Delivery newDelivery) {
        boolean result = false;
        if(null != newDelivery){
            if(null == this.deliveries){
                this.deliveries = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            if(this.deliveries.add(newDelivery))
            {
                result = true;
                if(null != this.owner){
                    newDelivery.setCostPerKg(this.owner.getDeliveryCost());
                }else{
                    newDelivery.setCostPerKg(Delivery.DEFAULTCOST);
                }
                newDelivery.registerObserver(this);
                this.notifyObservers();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addDeliveryWithCost(Delivery newDelivery, Double costPerKg)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        if(null != newDelivery && costPerKg >= Delivery.DEFAULTCOST){
            if(null == this.deliveries){
                this.deliveries = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            if(this.deliveries.add(newDelivery)){
                result = true;
                newDelivery.setCostPerKg(costPerKg);
                newDelivery.registerObserver(this);
                this.notifyObservers();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What about `deliveryRecord`?  What is `deliveryRecord`?

Comment: Added the part of the class where deliveryRecord is declared and the DeliveryRecord class

Comment: And when does `setDeliveryRecord` get called? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow thank you MadProgrammer when you said that it clicked with me. I added the line

```
objWindow.setDeliveryRecord(deliveryList);
```

To this button method on my main GUI:

```
private void btnAddDeliveryActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        AddDelivery objWindow = new AddDelivery();
        objWindow.setDeliveryRecord(deliveryList);
        objWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I also added this line to declare the deliveryList at the start of the class:

```
public DeliveryRecord deliveryList;
```